# How to evalute JSF EL Expressions which readed from DB

Tags: jsf, el, evaluation

I need to some sort of dynamic table in my project.
I have tried to use some configurations from database to generate my table.
I have stored some JPA field names in my DB and i want to retrieve their value
at run-time.
I need to something like this:

```
<h:datatable value="#{someBean.data}" var="record">
<ui:repeat value="#{someBean.columns}" var="column">
          <h:column>
              <h:ouputText value="#{record.column}"/>
          </h:column>
</ui:repeat>
</h:datatable>
```

But i don't know how to evaluate my stored EL  (record.column) especially when column contains reference to other entities for example column=

```
'someEntity.anOtherEntity.property'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put a `ui:repeat` component into an `h:dataTable` component to be able to access the property of `record`.  Simply this should do.

```
<h:datatable value="#{someBean.data}" var="record"> 
  <h:column> 
    <h:ouputText value="#{record.column.propertyOfColumn}"/> 
  </h:column>
</h:datatable>
```

This of course assumes that:

- A getter/setter property exists for `data` on `someBean` managed bean, Eg. `getData` `setData`
- A getter/setter property exists for `column` on the class type of dataTable var `record`.  Eg. `getColumn` and `setColumn`
- A getter/setter property exists for `propertOfColumn` on the class type of `column`.  Eg. `getPropertyOfColumn` and `setPropertyOfColumn`

Comment: no, my question is that if 'propertOfColumn' itself contains a chain of properties, i mean that propertOfColumn=someBean.relatedBean1.relatedBean2.property. getter and setters are exist but the propertOfColumn is read form DB runtime